# How to display line differences between 2 files while considering "modified lines"?

Tags: linux, scripting, diff

I have 2 files `file1` and `file2` that are sorted and contain mostly similar lines. I want to display added/modified/suppressed lines between these 2 files.

The catch is in the definition of a "modified line". I want to be able to give it as a input to the command.

For example, given the 2 following files (and its naive line format, which is a text followed by a colon and a number, where 2 modified lines are characterized by having the same text but a different number) :

> file1
>
> ```
> product1:4
> product2:5
> product3:6
> ```

> file2
>
> ```
> product1:7
> product3:6
> product4:9
> ```

I want the output (in any format) to give me that :

- 1 line was added: `product4:9`
- 1 line was deleted: `product2:5`
- 1 line was modified: `product1:4` became `product1:7`
- (and 1 line stayed the same: `product3:6`)

I don't mind if these are the output of a single command or different commands, whichever is simpler.

The following formula should hold:

```
(number of lines of file1) + (number of added lines) - (number of suppressed lines) = (number of lines of file2)
```

Edit:
For the example above, the regex input that is to be given to the program is `^(.+):[:digit:]+$`, so that the extracts for each line the text before the colon, and uses that extracted text to figure out if a line is similar to another one :

- if 2 given lines differ but the extracted text is the same for both, then this line is considered to have been modified
- if 2 given lines differ and the extracted text is different, then this line is considered to have been deleted and added.

Comment: How can we know if a line was "modified" and not "added"? Will we always have a string of letters with a number, then a `:` and another number? How can a program know that `product1:4` becoming `product1:7` is "modified" and not simply a case of deleting one line and inserting a new line? If you don't need to deal with this kind of "modification" which will need specific logic, you can just do `comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I would ideally like to give it as an argument to the algorithm. For example in this case, the regex would be something like `^(.+):[:digit:]+$`, and the first captured group is what is considered a similar line, so as long as only the number changes, the line is modified and not added/suppressed. Note that the question specifically asks how to deal with the problematic of "modified lines", otherwise a simple diff or comm would suffise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of key/value pairs, and the define added, removed and modified lines in terms of the keys, then it's not too hard. For instance, in `awk` with `:` as the separator:

```
$ $ awk -F: '{ if(NR==FNR){old[$1]=$2; line[$1]=$0} else{ seen[$1]++; if($1 in old){ if (old[$1] != $2){printf "Modified: %s became %s\n",line[$1],$0}else{print "Same: "$0}}else{print "Added: "$0}}}END{for(key in old){ if(!seen[key]){print "Deleted: "line[key]}}}' file1  file2 
Modified: product1:4 became product1:7
Same: product3:6
Added: product4:9
Deleted: product2:5
```

And here's the same thing a bit more legible:

```
awk -F: '
  { 
    if(NR==FNR){ 
        old[$1]=$2; 
        line[$1]=$0
    } 
    else{ 
        seen[$1]++; 
        if($1 in old){ 
            if (old[$1] != $2){
                printf "Modified: %s became %s\n",line[$1],$0
            }
            else{
                print "Same: "$0
            }
        }
        else{
            print "Added: "$0
        }
    }
  }
  END{
    for(key in old){ 
        if(!seen[key]){
            print "Deleted: "line[key]
        }
    }
}' file1  file2
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I could generalize this by stating when 2 lines are considered different, instead of using the `:` as separator ? For example by using the regex `^(.+):[:digit:]+$` ?

Comment: @mido probably, but I don't quite get what you mean. That regex is capturing all text from the beginning of the line until the last `:` before one or more numbers and the end of the line. I don't understand what you want to do from there. Maybe post a new question or expand this one? You could write a different program that takes two regexes, one to define the key and one to define the value and go from there.

Comment: What I mean is that the example files that I gave to explain my question easily and without knowing my context are more simple than my real life example. My real-life example lines are not of the form key:value. Rather, I want a program that takes only _one_ regex that extracts (as the first captured group) the part of the line that needs to be used as the string to figure out if two lines are "similar" (in other words, if any character differs appart from those from the regex, it should be considered a modified line). In the case of the example I gave, it would be `^(.+):[:digit:]+$`

Comment: I have appended an edit to my original question, please read it again and tell me if it is clearer. Basically what you said works, but only for the small example I provided, and not for a more general use case, which is what I'm ultimately looking for (see second paragraph of my question).

Comment: do you understand my question now ? Is it possible to do it with a captured group in a regex, or do you have a better idea ?